# Weird EF behaviour - unexpected long time

Tags: c#, database, performance, entity-framework

I have EF, database first. I have three model classes: `A`, `B` and `C`.
Model `A` has m2m relation to `B` and `B` has m2m relation to `C`.

I'm listing subset of `A` with related `B` and `C`.

In tested environment there in the subset there is about 20 models `A`, just few have any related `B` and if it has, it's just one in most cases.

Model `B` has always just one related `C`. I don't want to change it because in the future there will be more `C` related to one `B`.

My first approach was:

```
var listA = new Entities(...).As.Where(...).ToList();
foreach (var objA in listA){
    var listC = objA.Bs.ToList().Select(b => b.FirstOrDefault(c => ...)).ToList();
}
```

It took about 164ms - quite long.

So I thougt about optimizing it.

As you can see, in first line `IQueryable<A>` is changed to `List<A>`.
In this moment, I think, query is executed.

When I want to get `Bs` for `A` and `C` for `B`, another queries, I think, are executed.

Then I searched and found `Include` method. In the second approuch i used it like:

```
var listA = new Entities(...).As.Include("Bs.Cs").Where(...).ToList();
foreach (var objA in listA){
    var listC = objA.Bs.ToList().Select(b => b.FirstOrDefault(c => ...)).ToList();
}
```

In my opinion execution should take about 10ms, but now it is taking 550ms.

When I just listing `As` withoud related `Bs` and `Cs` it is taking about 10ms.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry, C has FK to B. But I don't think it changes anything.

Comment: You really should investigate the emitted sql for any unexpected queries.

Answer (score 0):

If your DbContext support lazy loading "which is true by default" that will produce many hits to Database whenever you call `objA.Bs.ToList()` and `b => b.FirstOrDefault(c => ...)` **that's because you didn't included these navigational properties in your first `listA` query**.

**Anyway try to use Include method**

```
var listA = new Entities(...).As.Include("Bs").Include("Bs.Cs").Where(...).ToList();
```

Comment: In my second approach I included "Bs" and "Bs.Cs" (`Include("Bs").Include("Bs.Cs")` works the same as just `Include("Bs.Cs")`) and it is even works slower than before.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience explicit loading of related objects are a little bit faster. Please try loading using objects Load() method and use IsLoaded to check if it is already loaded. Additionaly turning off lazy loading and explicitly opening connection may help.

Something like the following may help.

```
var listA = from o in context where (...) select o;
foreach (var i in listA)
            {
                if (!i.Bs.IsLoaded)
                    i.Bs.Load();
                if (i.Bs != null)
                {
                    if (!i.Bs.Cs.IsLoaded)
                        i.Bs.Cs.Load();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it create one db query for each of A elements?

Comment: if some of the Bs are the same for different As then no, otherwise yes. In my test it seems ~20% faster than include but I have no formal test results.